# Match using metric name instead of metric labels

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

One of my exporters prints a metric with no labels:

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:9999/metrics | grep service_up | grep -v "#"
service_up 1
```

When creating an AlertManager receiver usualy I use one of the metric labels for the `match` (e.g., `job: 'nodeexporter-textcollector'`).

E.g., here's what the AlertManager config look like for that case:

```
route:
  receiver: 'default'
  routes:
  - receiver: 'custom'
    match:
      severity: 'critical'
      job: 'nodeexporter-textcollector'
```

However, for the above metric (`service_up`) is it possible to match against the metric name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined an alerting rule to this metric, correct? Something like the following example:

```
- alert: ServiceIsDown
  expr: service_up == 0
```

Now, to route this alert, you just need to use the alert name:

```
route:
  receiver: 'default'
  routes:
  - receiver: 'custom'
    match:
      alertname: 'ServiceIsDown'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom named alert and put the right tags on it.  For example `severity` like in this example.

```
# alerts/example-redis.yml
groups:

- name: ExampleRedisGroup
  rules:
  - alert: ExampleRedisDown
    expr: redis_up{} == 0
    for: 2m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: "Redis instance down"
      description: "Whatever"
```

Also, pay attention to `expr`  field, it is how alermanager will understand that it need trigger an alert.Just check `alerts` folder in your alertmanager distribution, there are a lot of examples.

Official documentation about creating alerts: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/alerting_rules/

More examples of custom alerts: https://awesome-prometheus-alerts.grep.to/alertmanager